Integrating a Flask Backend with a NextJS frontend, files not received with POST action
I have a Flask Backend, whose purpose is to receive a file, and process it. Now I've got a Next frontend, in which I've got a file upload. Now when I did the exact steps with a template html file within the flask project it actually did work, but when I did the same steps using my Next app, no files are being sent. These are the following files.
Flask App
@app.route('/result', methods=['GET','POST'])
def mainProcessingAPI():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        checkFolderStruct()
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return ('Please Enter A file')
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = f"{setInstanceCounter()}_{secure_filename(file.filename)}"
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            processFile(filename)

            return render_template('result.html')
        else:
             return render_template('error.html'), {"Refresh": "3; url=http://localhost:5000/"}

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])

def mainApp():
    return render_template('index.html') #Not Used Anymore. (Works with upload though)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost',port=5000, debug=True)



Index.html, (where the file upload works correctly)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>File input test</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data action="http://localhost:5000/result">
        <input type=file name=file>
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
      </form>
</body>
</html>

Next App
<form action="http://localhost:5000/result" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">

          
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-full" onDrop={(event) =>handleDrop(event) } onDragOver={(event) => handleDragover(event)}>
            <label htmlFor="dropzone-file"  className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-64 border-2 border-gray-900 border-dashed rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-[#121212] dark:bg-[#212121] hover:bg-gray-100 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:border-gray-500 ">
                <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-5 pb-6">
                    <svg className="w-8 h-8 mb-4 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 20 16">
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 13h3a3 3 0 0 0 0-6h-.025A5.56 5.56 0 0 0 16 6.5 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 5.207 5.021C5.137 5.017 5.071 5 5 5a4 4 0 0 0 0 8h2.167M10 15V6m0 0L8 8m2-2 2 2"/>
                    </svg>
                    <p className="mb-2 text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"><span className="font-semibold">Click to upload</span> or drag and drop</p>
                    <p className="text-xs text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">.CSV only</p>
                </div>
                <input id="dropzone-file" type="file" className="" onInput={(event) => handleUpload(event)}/>
            </label>
        </div> 
      <p className="mb-4"><span className="font-semibold">Selected file:</span> {uploadName}</p>
       
      
      <input type="submit" className={classNames("p-4 w-full border-2 rounded-lg  dark:border-gray-600  ",{ "text-gray-500 dark:bg-[#2e2e2e]":!uploaded, "cursor-pointer dark:hover:border-gray-500  dark:bg-[#212121] dark:hover:bg-[#121212]":uploaded}) } ></input>
      </form>


I would recommend using an API test tool like www.postman.com to test your endpoints separately to your frontend. You can use this, along with logging to see where the problem lies.

Changing the input's name to "file" fixed it all
<input id="dropzone-file" name="file" type="file" className="" onInput={(event) => handleUpload(event)}/>
